# What’s the difference between the LESS color functions lighten and tint?

Tags: colors, less

Both `lighten` and `tint` seem to make a color lighter (closer to white). Why does LESS define both?

From [the LESS documentation](http://lesscss.org/#reference):

> `lighten(@color, 10%);  // return a color 10% points *lighter*`
>
> `tint(@color, 10%);     // return a color mixed 10% with white`

How [one site](http://www.workwithcolor.com/color-properties-definitions-0101.htm#tint) defines **tint** (note the use of the word “lighter”):

> If you tinted a color, you've been adding white to the original color.
>
> A tint is lighter than the original color.

Comment: Seems like `tint` and `shade` have been completely removed from the docs... But it's still working (1.7.0).

Comment: Update: It appears that `tint` and `shade` are back in the docs now, so if you were worried (like I was), it seems like they're still safe to use, at least as of v2.7.1: http://lesscss.org/functions/#color-operations-tint

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [this thread](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/944) that was asking for `tint` comes [this comment](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/944#issuecomment-8417318):

> Tint/shade is not the same thing as lighten/darken. Tint and shade are
>   effectively mixing with white and black respectively, whereas
>   lighten/darken are manuipulating the luminance channel independently
>   of hue and saturation. The former can produce hue shifts, whereas the
>   latter does not. That's not to say it's not useful, just that it's not
>   the same thing. Mathematically it's that linear changes in RGB space
>   do not necessarily correspond with linear changes in HSL space, though
>   in practice they will produce fairly similar results.

There is a slight difference in the math behind the two.

Comment: Great thread, thanks. So it’s `tint` that an alter the hue. I had it backwards.

Answer (score 7):

Both functions produce a 'lighter' color somehow but use different methods to do so.

Take a look at [the source](https://github.com/less/less.js/blob/1a184d5790f8abc0deb4f5a7726fb4ddbe0ca09a/lib/less/functions.js) to see how they work:

```
tint: function(color, amount) {
    return this.mix(this.rgb(255,255,255), color, amount);
},
```

```
lighten: function (color, amount) {
    var hsl = color.toHSL();

    hsl.l += amount.value / 100;
    hsl.l = clamp(hsl.l);
    return hsla(hsl);
},
```

So `tint` is mixing in white (as stated by the documentation) and `lighten` increases the *lightness* of in the HSL color model.

Comment: Thanks for the source code link and snippets. You answered the question well. I accepted ScottS’s answer because it gives a higher-level analysis and the motivation for having both.

Answer (score 3):

Here’s [a demonstration of both functions](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/iFfcD).

It seems `lighten` and `darken` reach white and black, respectively, much faster than `tint` and `shade`.

To my untrained eye, it also appears that `lighten` and `darken` can alter the hue, whereas `tint` and `shade` do not.